# Table floating header is also adding and extra vertical scroll-bar in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In internet explorer, table floating headers are also adding extra vertical scrollbar in table and a little white-space at table bottom. But changing font-size from 17px to 16px removes the extra scroll-bar and whitespace. Is there a way to use font-size 17px without adding an extra scroll-bar and without extra whitespace at table bottom in internet explorer?

fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/bsxx39vo/`
My screen size is 1366x768 and os windows 10.

This problem is also in firefox at some zoom levels.

And i am totally unable to understand why is this happening.

Js:

```
/*
 * jQuery throttle / debounce - v1.1 - 3/7/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */
(function(b,c){var $=b.jQuery||b.Cowboy||(b.Cowboy={}),a;$.throttle=a=function(e,f,j,i){var h,d=0;if(typeof f!=="boolean"){i=j;j=f;f=c}function g(){var o=this,m=+new Date()-d,n=arguments;function l(){d=+new Date();j.apply(o,n)}function k(){h=c}if(i&&!h){l()}h&&clearTimeout(h);if(i===c&&m>e){l()}else{if(f!==true){h=setTimeout(i?k:l,i===c?e-m:e)}}}if($.guid){g.guid=j.guid=j.guid||$.guid++}return g};$.debounce=function(d,e,f){return f===c?a(d,e,false):a(d,f,e!==false)}})(this);







$(function(){
    $('table').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('thead').length > 0 && $(this).find('th').length > 0) {
            // Clone <thead>
            var $w     = $(window),
                $t     = $(this),
                $thead = $t.find('thead').clone(),
                $col   = $t.find('thead, tbody').clone();

            // Add class, remove margins, reset width and wrap table
            $t
            .addClass('sticky-enabled')
            .css({
                margin: 0,
                width: '100%'
            }).wrap('<div class="sticky-wrap" />');

            if($t.hasClass('overflow-y')) $t.removeClass('overflow-y').parent().addClass('overflow-y');

            // Create new sticky table head (basic)
            $t.after('<table class="sticky-thead" />');

            // If <tbody> contains <th>, then we create sticky column and intersect (advanced)
            if($t.find('tbody th').length > 0) {
                $t.after('<table class="sticky-col" /><table class="sticky-intersect" />');
            }

            // Create shorthand for things
            var $stickyHead  = $(this).siblings('.sticky-thead'),
                $stickyCol   = $(this).siblings('.sticky-col'),
                $stickyInsct = $(this).siblings('.sticky-intersect'),
                $stickyWrap  = $(this).parent('.sticky-wrap');

            $stickyHead.append($thead);

            $stickyCol
            .append($col)
                .find('thead th:gt(0)').remove()
                .end()
                .find('tbody td').remove();

            $stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>'+$t.find('thead th:first-child').html()+'</th></tr></thead>');

            // Set widths
            var setWidths = function () {
                    $t
                    .find('thead th').each(function (i) {
                        $stickyHead.find('th').eq(i).width($(this).width());
                    })
                    .end()
                    .find('tr').each(function (i) {
                        $stickyCol.find('tr').eq(i).height($(this).height());
                    });

                    // Set width of sticky table head
                    $stickyHead.width($t.width());

                    // Set width of sticky table col
                    $stickyCol.find('th').add($stickyInsct.find('th')).width($t.find('thead th').width())
                },
                repositionStickyHead = function () {
                    // Return value of calculated allowance
                    var allowance = calcAllowance();

                    // Check if wrapper parent is overflowing along the y-axis
                    if($t.height() > $stickyWrap.height()) {
                        // If it is overflowing (advanced layout)
                        // Position sticky header based on wrapper scrollTop()
                        if($stickyWrap.scrollTop() > 0) {
                            // When top of wrapping parent is out of view
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                opacity: 1,
                                top: $stickyWrap.scrollTop()
                            });
                        } else {
                            // When top of wrapping parent is in view
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                opacity: 0,
                                top: 0
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        // If it is not overflowing (basic layout)
                        // Position sticky header based on viewport scrollTop
                        if($w.scrollTop() > $t.offset().top && $w.scrollTop() < $t.offset().top + $t.outerHeight() - allowance) {
                            // When top of viewport is in the table itself
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                opacity: 1,
                                top: $w.scrollTop() - $t.offset().top
                            });
                        } else {
                            // When top of viewport is above or below table
                            $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                                opacity: 0,
                                top: 0
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                repositionStickyCol = function () {
                    if($stickyWrap.scrollLeft() > 0) {
                        // When left of wrapping parent is out of view
                        $stickyCol.add($stickyInsct).css({
                            opacity: 1,
                            left: $stickyWrap.scrollLeft()
                        });
                    } else {
                        // When left of wrapping parent is in view
                        $stickyCol
                        .css({ opacity: 0 })
                        .add($stickyInsct).css({ left: 0 });
                    }
                },
                calcAllowance = function () {
                    var a = 0;
                    // Calculate allowance
                    $t.find('tbody tr:lt(3)').each(function () {
                        a += $(this).height();
                    });

                    // Set fail safe limit (last three row might be too tall)
                    // Set arbitrary limit at 0.25 of viewport height, or you can use an arbitrary pixel value
                    if(a > $w.height()*0.25) {
                        a = $w.height()*0.25;
                    }

                    // Add the height of sticky header
                    a += $stickyHead.height();
                    return a;
                };

            setWidths();

            $t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(15, function() {
                repositionStickyHead();
                repositionStickyCol();
            }));

            $w
            .load(setWidths)
            .resize($.debounce(250, function () {
                setWidths();
                repositionStickyHead();
                repositionStickyCol();
            }))
            .scroll($.throttle(15, repositionStickyHead));
        }
    });
});
```

Css:

```
body{ margin:0; font-size:17px; color:#333; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; line-height:1.8em; background:#fff; -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale; }
a{ color:#333; }

table{ border-spacing:0; white-space:nowrap; cursor:default; line-height:1.4em; }
table thead th{ border:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background:#339966; color:#eee; padding:16px 8px; font-weight:normal; -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none; -khtml-user-select:none; }
table thead th a{ color:#fff; }
table thead th a:hover{ color:#54b9f8; }
table tbody th{ border:1px solid #fff; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background:#ddd; color:#222; padding:16px 8px; font-weight:normal; -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout:none; -khtml-user-select:none; }
table tbody th a{ color:#222; }
table tbody th a:hover{ color:#076cab; }
table td{ padding:8px; border:1px solid #ccc; }
table > thead > tr > th{ vertical-align:top; }

.sticky-wrap{ position:relative; overflow-x:auto; margin:80px 1% 90px; }
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead, .sticky-wrap .sticky-col, .sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect{ position:absolute; top:0; }
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect{ opacity:1; z-index:10; display:none; }
.sticky-wrap td, .sticky-wrap th{ box-sizing:border-box; }

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead{ transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition:all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out; box-shadow:0em 0.1em 0.4em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -moz-box-shadow:0em 0.1em 0.4em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); -webkit-box-shadow:0em 0.1em 0.4em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }

.sticky-wrap .sticky-col { transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition:all 0.125s 0.1s ease-in-out; box-shadow:0.1em 0em 0.4em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.5); -moz-box-shadow:0.1em 0em 0.4em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.5); -webkit-box-shadow:0.1em 0em 0.4em 0em rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
```

Html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Platforms</th>
            <th scope="col">domain options</th>
            <th scope="col">hosting available</th>
            <th scope="col"><em>bandwidth</em></th>
            <th scope="col">customer support&nbsp;</th>
            <th colspan="2" rowspan="1" scope="col">ease of use&nbsp;community&nbsp;<br />
            ratings</th>
            <th scope="col"><strong><em>&nbsp;user ratings</em></strong></th>
            <th scope="col">pros</th>
            <th scope="col">cons</th>
            <th scope="col">cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="https://www.blogger.com/">Blogger</a></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>12gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>lack of many features</td>
            <td>$1000.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><em><a href="https://wordpress.com/">Wordpress</a></em></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td><em>12gb</em></td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td><em>&nbsp;very good support and users support</em></td>
            <td>&nbsp;lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="https://wordpress.com/">Tumblr</a></th>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>23gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>Free of cost</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="4" scope="row"><a href="https://wordpress.com/">Typepad</a></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td rowspan="3">no</td>
            <td rowspan="3"><a href="http://www.wix.com/">12gb</a></td>
            <td rowspan="3">-</td>
            <td rowspan="3">8</td>
            <td rowspan="3">6</td>
            <td rowspan="4"><a href="http://comparisonsheet.com/">7</a></td>
            <td rowspan="4">user friendly, and <a href="http://www.wix.com/">very</a> easy</td>
            <td rowspan="4"><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">very few plugins</a></td>
            <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>available</td>
            <td>limited upload</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="https://www.blogger.com/">CMS1</a></th>
            <td><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">yes</a></td>
            <td><strong>yes</strong></td>
            <td>0gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>highly customizable and flexible</td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">$1000.00 per year</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="https://www.blogger.com/">CMS2</a></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>e<a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">23gb</a></td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="http://www.typepad.com/">Movabletype</a></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>4gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">5</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td><strong>easy to maintain</strong></td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">squarespace</th>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>unlimited download</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td colspan="2">9</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><em>user friendly, and very easy</em></td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>$1000.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">wp.org</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>1gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>Free of cost</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="https://www.blogger.com/">blogger</a></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>12gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">9</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.wix.com/">user friendly, and very easy</a></td>
            <td>lack of many features</td>
            <td>$1000.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">wordpress</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.wix.com/">12gb</a></td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">8</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>&nbsp;very good support and users support</td>
            <td>&nbsp;lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">tumblr</th>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>23gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>Free of cost</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="http://www.typepad.com/">typepad</a></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>12gb</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td colspan="2">8</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">cms1</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>0gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.wix.com/">highly customizable and flexible</a></td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>$1000.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">cms2</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>23gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">movabletype</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>4gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">5</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>easy to maintain</td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="http://www.typepad.com/">squarespace</a></th>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">unlimited download</a></td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td colspan="2">9</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>$1000.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="http://www.typepad.com/">wp.org</a></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>1gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>Free of cost</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="http://www.typepad.com/">blogger</a></th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">yes</a></td>
            <td><em>12gb</em></td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">9</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td><em>user friendly, and very easy</em></td>
            <td>lack of many features</td>
            <td>$1000.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">wordpress</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>12gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">8</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">&nbsp;very good support and users support</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">tumblr</th>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>23gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">Free of cost</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">typepad</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>12gb</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td colspan="2">8</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">cms1</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>0gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.typepad.com/pricing">highly customizable and flexible</a></td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>$1000.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">cms2</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>23gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">movabletype</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>4gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">5</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>easy to maintain</td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;$500.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">squarespace</th>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>unlimited download</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td colspan="2">9</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>very few plugins</td>
            <td>$1000.00 per year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">wp.org</th>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td>1gb</td>
            <td>yes</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>user friendly, and very easy</td>
            <td>lack of enough themes</td>
            <td>Free of cost</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: could we by any chance see a not obfuscated version of the code? :) Cannot tell what is going on in that javascript - it must be hard to maintain or debug after 3 months :)

Comment: thanks for comment i updated the question and scripts

Comment: @davidkonrad if you have any idea about this bug please tell me because i am not an expert in jquery and i need anyones little help to start debug, thanks.